# Unable to import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'; TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJs testing, i am trying to run npm test, it was working fine until i installed enzyme-adapter-react-16. I am getting below error. TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

```
  1 | import { configure } from 'enzyme';
> 2 | import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
    | ^
  3 | configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

I tried different ways to solve the problem I added setupTests.js file 
and i deleted npm module folder, i deletd package.lock.json, installed npm again none off them worked.

setupTests.js

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

App.test.js

```
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.0.2",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.0.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

It used to run fine until I install enzyme.

Comment: how did you install enzyme? via npm using command line or by editing package.json and then running npm

Comment: Through npm only.                                                                                              npm add jest-environment-enzyme jest-enzyme enzyme-adapter-react-16 --dev